# Unblock a drain after using too much baking soda

Tags: plumbing, drain

I had a smelly drain in my bathroom after moving into a new house. I tried baking soda and vinegar but the smell remained. I decided to poor the rest of the box of baking soda down the drain and let it sit for a while. I followed it by warm vinegar and hot water...and now I have a blocked drain which I never had to begin with! Please help! How do I unblock it?

Comment: can you get to the water trap and remove it?

Comment: Um...I don't think there's a water trap. My husband isn't home at the moment so no, I can't really do that...is there nothing I can pour down the drain that would help?

Comment: Chances are you drain was pretty clogged and by unclogging the top part you stuffed the bottom where the original issue was.  You will need to snake it or use some chemicals (bleach works a lot of times).

Comment: If there's no water in the trap, then it's not working correctly or you have a venting problem. There should always be water in the trap to keep sewer gases from entering your home.

Answer (score 4):

A weak acid is the way to deal with a plug of baking soda. It'll turn the plug material into CO2 and a soluble sodium salt of the acid.
It'll take quite a bit of acid to deal with a pound of bicarb though, 84 grams is 5.4 moles of the stuff.
Regular vinegar runs at 5% acid strength, that's abot 200 grams per gallon, 3.3 moles. So you'd need abot 1.6 gallons to deal with a pound of impacted bicarb. A single gallon might do the trick though, as all you need to do is destabilize the plug, at which point the rest will wash through.

Citric acid would be a nice choice. It's easy to get, but with a molecular mass of 192, and a price around $6 for 200 grams (~1 mol), it's too expensive.

Finally, if your plumbing will take it, and you're comfortable around strong acids, hydrochloric acid (muriatic acid) would do the job. Muriatic can be had cheap at any good hardware store. Since it comes at a concentration of about 10 molar, it'll only take about 500 ml to take care of a pound of bicarb. At full strength, it'll foam and heat and boil while acting on the carbonate, so dilute with at least a gallon of water first to keep things manageable; and only try this approach if you're OK with working with around nasty, smelly, dangerous, irritating chemicals.

Trying to use lye, Drano or some other basic drain cleaner on this problem is a futile pursuit. Bicarb responds to **acids**, not bases.

Comment: I agree.  I gave bleach as a solution in because it is cheap, usually already in the home, and will eat through anything eventually.  Your solutions are better but usually not in the home.  I would only add that she will have to snake this eventually.  Something was causing a clog.

Comment: Trouble with bleach, is that it's basic, with a pH around 9.5. Something around pH 4 or lower is needed. Vinegar is the most home-available source of that.

Comment: In this case I would be just as concerned with the other stuff gunking up the pipe as the baking soda.  If you pour a half gallon of bleach down a sink drain it will make its way to the other side or you have to snake.  However this could take a while compared to your choices.

Comment: I simply cannot advocate putting any significant amount of strong acid down the drain (tho vinegar should be fine)! The reaction between a strong acid and the baking soda can evolve gas so quickly that you'll blast acid back up the drain and all over your bathroom.  I could even envision rupturing the pipes depending on where the acid reacts with the soda.  Last, when this method fails, which it probably will, then the plumber you call will have to deal with strong acid! If it is a bathroom sink, there has to be a trap.  Remove the trap and snake if the soda is downstream of there.

Answer (score 3):

Baking soda powder will turn into a cement like mass and completely clog everything it settles in.

I had a family member dump about three cups down the kitchen sink this summer and I ended up having to replace the trap, tailpiece and dishwasher drain inflow.

In this case, it was set up so hard that a snake couldn't even budge it. If that's the case, it's plumber time.

And next time you use it, do not pour washing soda **powder** down the drain. It must be mixed thoroughly in solution, completely dissolved in water so it will flush through the system.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise against pouring gallons of Draino and equivalents down the drain - you can try the recommended dose once and if it doesn't work - get a snake. I recently battled a really nasty clog which resisted everything - except for a snake. Since it's in the bathroom, you will probably be dealing with lots of hair and soap gunk, which is difficult for the chemicals to chew through anyway. If you have access to a trap or cleanout, feed the auger through that.

Now, the key advice about the snake is spend a bit of money on a thicker cable and get an auto-feeding snake. It will make it so much easier for you. After a lot of swearing, banging my head under the sink, and finally kinking a cheapo auger I bought this one from Home Depot: http://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-Kwik-Spin-41348/203203829
Don't be tempted to get a power-drill snake, as those are overkill and can hurt you.

If all else fails and you can't unclog it, remember that it's OK to give up and call a pro.

P.S. Soda & vinegar are great for *maintaining* drains regularly, but if you skip doing it, gunk will build up and you risk dislodging it next time you use soda. Ask me how I know.

Answer (score 2):

Try a plunger first and with persistence. If that doesn't work, snake it.

I don't think you'll solve this by pouring chemicals in there, and the potential for "collateral damage" (and not to mention, safety concerns) with having a pipe full of chemicals is worth the extra effort involved in the mechanical solutions.

Comment: Sodium bicarbonate is a chemical. The old brittle pvc pipe that the sink drain is constructed from is a chemical, and may well crack when too much force is applied with a snake. Vinegar, being a chemical too, is probably as kind and gentle a cure as you'll find.

Answer (score 1):

Try a plunger or a snake. More hot water might also help, if you can get it to the drain (possibly sponge out the water currently in the basin.)

Adding more chemicals to the drain is probably not going to help at this point, and will make dealing with the backed up water more dangerous if you use typical "drain cleaners" on it. Those rarely work well in any case, IMPE.

Try pulling out the stopper - in many cases there's a buildup of hair, and things that collected on the hair, trapped in the lower part of the stopper.

Answer (score 0):

Did the house sit empty for a while before you moved in? Could be the trap dried out and your smelling sewer gas. Just using the drain would fix that.

Since you dumped so much powder in there I'd just put a bucket under the trap to catch stuff and remove the trap to clean it out if it's the sink and it's easy to get to. The "J" portion under the sink is designed to keep a slug of water in it after the sink drains to keep you from smelling sewer gas.

If it's the bath tub a cheap plastic snake or a real one might loosen up the plug of baking powder.

In the future if drains clog try the plunger 1st. If not try a little draino. Any off brand is the same stuff and will eat hair which is usually what clogs the drain. A screen in the tub will keep end of soap bars out of the trap.

Plumbers love the vinegar, lemon in the garbage disposal, bleach in the toilet etc.
They know they'll eventually get a call to repair the damage. Bleach kills the flapper rubber etc in the tank. Lemon rind in the garbage disposal rots the metal.

Answer (score 0):

If your drain is clogged and you think it’s from hardened baking soda, don’t panic—it can be fixed, despite how scary hardened baking soda sounds from the other answers. You don’t have to use a scary acid either. Water started to pool during a shower, so I removed the drain cover and used a ZipIt (plastic tool with barbs aimed up) and removed a ton of hair. I should have stopped there. But After that, because it smelled a little, I dumped about 2-3 cups of baking soda into the shower drain. (In hindsight that was too much. Do NOT do that! Even if it smells.) I followed that with food grade vinegar. I ran the water a little later and it seemed fine. Two showers later water was pooling again. I then poured 3/4 of a gallon of vinegar down. That didn’t clear it. Then a week later without using the shower at all, more vinegar. No dice. We tried to snake it and not being experienced, the snake was hitting something but not clearing it. I did a Google search and became terrified that the baking soda had hardened we’d never be able to fix this, and we’d have to rip through Sheetrock (this is upstairs) and who knows what else would be necessary because it’s a shower not a sink. I called a plumber thinking he’d have to snake it, but he dumped a little Glug into the pipe. He Waited for it to fizz. (It did). He poured hot water down using a 2 pound container. It seemed fixed but then we turned on the sink (hot water) and it started to back up. So he turned everything off and dumped a little more Glug down. he kept dumping hot water down using large a large bucket and then running the shower and the sinks for a while while also using the bucket to make sure it was clear. All this took a half hour. My plumber used Glug and it worked. If you’re going to try using it yourself it looked like clumps of powered which I think was the crystal formula.  My point is to reassure readers that all is not lost if you put down too much baking soda. But I will never again—never ever-put any baking soda down the drain. (He said the Glug would act on the hair and soap and the baking soda. I said to him twice that I was so worried it hardened and couldn’t be fixed.) I am relieved it’s clear! (I have seen videos where baking soda and vinegar worked for people’s clogged drains but I will never use it again. (I posted my experience because there are almost no other warnings on the internet to people not to use baking soda because it will harden. There’s a zillion videos telling people to clear clogs with vinegar and baking soda. As for showers I’d recommend getting one of those round metal disc with small holes to put on top of your drain first, if you can, removing the hair it catches after each shower, or using a ZipIt every several months or so to snake the pipe, before the water starts to back up. If you get a clog, use Glug. If that doesn’t work, call a plumber.)

Comment: Hi Becky, it's too hard to read.  PLease edit and split it into shorter sentences and multiple paragraphs